# Mysql Server serving to LO / OOO Base to Multi users sessions merge

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am serving MYSQL on my Local but Remote Server to a number of terminals set up to connect a Libre Base front-end via JDBC

The server is a Ubuntu 14.04 asterisk box serving well and I have only recently added the Database to serve the librebase mysql which it does using the java JDBC

Each user can build their form document without any issues,

however,

It seems as if all sessions are merged when delivering reports, as in whoever has the lock , that's the report MYSQL serves, in other words user "A" gets user "B" reports if user "B" was the last to do something.

"SHOW PROCESSLIST;" indicates different thread-Id's for each user

Comment: Are the users opening the same copy of the front-end .odb file (i.e., a copy located on a server share)? If so, have you tried giving two test users their own local copy of the .odb file to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: The same copy but NOT on server share -- all have their own copy on their terminal with their own user name

Comment: Well, I do not think it is the server, I just completed testing on another "Test Server" set up specifically to check this and I get the same error . . .

Comment: Problem was that Filter Table Keeps a single entry at a time  This meant that, as we know, the Filter Table is used for Selection only and not used thereafter except for pulling reports and the like. The terminals could work independently but the reports pulled were based on the last entry in the Filter Table, Frustrating, as when a terminal had to pull a report then they would first have to change the Filter Table entry to then pull the necessary reports.

Turns out the issue has nothing to do with MYSQL, SERVER or CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final Macro

---

REM 
Sub ReportMacro (oEvent as Object) 
Rem Getting ticket Number
    dim CUSTOMERS
    dim sTicketID as string 
    dim oCreateButton,oForm 
    dim oConnection,oReportsDocuments

Rem SEtting the Connection etc
    oCreateButton=oEvent.source.model
    oForm=oCreateButton.parent
    oConnection = oForm.ActiveConnection.createStatement()

REM First Clean / Delete the filter table

sSQL="DELETE  FROM MacBase.Filter "

'   print " End of Delete,Now find TicketNumber "

```
CUSTOMERS = oEvent.Source.Model.Parent  
sTicketID = CUSTOMERS.getstring( CUSTOMERS.FindColumn( "TicketNumber" ) )
```

'   print "Currently Printing record  with Ticket No =" & sTicketID

Rem now Move ahead with pulling the report, standard basic

```
oForm=oCreateButton.parent
oConnection=oForm.Activeconnection  
oReportsDocuments=oConnection.parent.DatabaseDocument.ReportDocuments
openReport(oConnection, oReportsDocuments, oCreateButton.tag , oForm.Filter)
```

' print "Finished with openReport Befor end Sub " & sTicketID
End Sub

Function openReport(oConnection, oReportsDocuments,aReportName,sFilter) as object

Dim mPrintopts1()

```
   dim aProp(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
   dim aProp2
   dim oReportDesign
   aProp(1).Name = "ActiveConnection"
   aProp(1).Value = oConnection
   aProp(0).Name = "Hidden"
   aProp(0).Value = true   
   aProp(2).Name = "OpenMode"
   aProp(2).Value = "openDesign"
   let aProp2=aProp 
   oReportDesign=oReportsDocuments.loadComponentFromURL(aReportName ,"",0,aProp())

   aProp2(0).Value = TRUE
   aProp2(2).Value = "open"
```

oReportsDocuments.loadComponentFromURL(aReportName ,_blank,0,aProp2()).Print(mPrintopts1())

End Function

---